# Как сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки проигрывался аудио файл?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Когда нажимаешь на кнопку производился аудиофайл. как это сделать?

Comment: Пример может быть на <embed>, <bgsound> Вопрос нормальный, можно было не закрывать. Не всю же жизнь нажжимать эту кнопку в стандартной панели <audio controls>.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант на jQuery

```
let sound = new Audio();

$('elem').on('click', function(){
  sound.src = 'ссылка на аудио';
  sound.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = 'sound.ogg';

document.querySelector('.play').addEventListener("click", _ => {
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<button class="play">Play<button>
```

Comment: Добавьте скобки audio.play()

Comment: Олег, что? зачем?)

Comment: А что, фунциклирует без них? :)

Comment: document.queryselector('.play').onclick = function(){audio.play()}; так без скобок не будет работать.

Comment: Олег, да, всё верно, спасибо за замечание